# While loop overwrite

Tags: python, while-loop, infinite-loop

```
choice = None
while choice != 0:
    print("Hello")

    choice = 0
```

In this circumstance why does the string "Hello" only print once? Shouldn't choice reset to None after the ending of the while loop, thus resulting in an infinite print("Hello")?

Comment: Why do you think `choice` would reset to `None`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix it, try doing this:

```
choice = None
while choice != 0:
    print("Hello")

choice = 0
```

Since you indented the last line, Python thought it was part of your loop.